# SQL Server if statement does not execute as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am trying to use the following stored procedure but there are some instances WHERE only the incremental happens AND the code does not run. What I need is that, when the program enters the IF statement, either it should run both the statements or None.

Stored procedure goes like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spflpunch]
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @id NUMERIC(18,0)
    DECLARE @studname NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @punchtime DATETIME
    DECLARE @samedaycount NUMERIC(2)

    SELECT @id = (MAX(lastid)) FROM [smartswype].[dbo].[read]
    PRINT @id

    SELECT @studname = studname 
    FROM [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview] 
    WHERE id  =@id
    PRINT @studname

    SELECT @punchtime = punchtime 
    FROM [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview] 
    WHERE id = @id

    PRINT @punchtime

    --SELECT @punchvarchar = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@punchtime, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @punchtime, 14)

    IF @id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview])
    BEGIN
        SELECT @samedaycount = COUNT(*) 
        FROM [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview] 
        WHERE (studname = @studname 
          AND CONVERT(DATE, punchtime) = CONVERT(DATE, @punchtime)) -- If firstpunch = 1 then it is the first punch

        PRINT @samedaycount

        IF @samedaycount =1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [smartswype].[dbo].[firstlastpunch] ([studname], [DATE], [punch1], [punch2])
            VALUES(@studname, CONVERT(DATE, @punchtime), @punchtime, NULL);

            UPDATE [smartswype].[dbo].[read] 
            SET lastid = @id + 1;
        END
        ELSE IF (@samedaycount > 1)  
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [smartswype].[dbo].[firstlastpunch]
            SET punch2 = @punchtime 
            WHERE (studname = @studname AND DATE = CONVERT(DATE, @punchtime));

            UPDATE [smartswype].[dbo].[read] 
            SET lastid = @id + 1;
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: is this a good bool check? `if @id = (select max(id) from [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview])`, try `select @id = max(id) from [SSWYPE_WEBDB].[dbo].[attdview])`, I doubt it did not go forward and ends there

Comment: What is incremental happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that both or none of the statements run, you should wrap the contents of the if statement in a transaction.

By wrapping it in a transaction, you can ensure that if one statement fails, that the other statement will not run.

Here is a link to the docs on transactions in SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql